# not allowed to call function inside other function in wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

Im having dificulties to get this little plugin running.

```
function latest_price(){
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT bid,ask FROM wp_ticker ORDER BY indate DESC limit 1");

$price = $result[0]->bid;
return $price;
}

 function outputprice(){
 $output = $this->latest_price();
echo $output;
}


add_shortcode ('getprice', 'outputprice');
```

when i try to run this shortcode on a wordpress page, the page doesnt load. when i turn on debugging i dont see any errors though?
Is this kind of structuring allowed or should i use OOP and put the functions in a class?

Comment: Without a class, `$this` does not make much sense.

Comment: Beside the issue of $this, are you sure $result is working? Also, a shortcode shouldn't echo anything, just return some html...